# How to connect to external network hard drive as a different user?

Tags: nautilus, samba, external-hdd

I can access my external network hard drive with Files in Ubuntu 14.04.2. It is 2 TB WD hard drive and I guess its file system is NTFS and I guess (again) that samba is used here.

First time I connected as an anonymous user. Now I want to connect as a different user who has rights to access other folders than Public. However, on double click it does not offer login as different user.

How do I delete does credentials so that I have again a choice to connect as an anonymous or some other user?

Comment: How did you access that hard drive? Do you use samba? Are you connecting using `connect to server` ?

Comment: No, just `Browse Network` in Files (Nautilus) and double click on its name there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open files again then go to the Menu `File` then choose `connect-to-server`

[image]

This will open the following

[image]

In the server address write the IP of your client in the form `smb://192.168.1.1` replace the IP with you client

then enter the user name and password and that's.